# htaccess RewriteRule results in 404 response

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a website that is in the root folder. It has a `.htaccess` with teh code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

When I open `http://example.com/login/` I get a "404 Not Found" error but when I open `http://example.com/login` without the trailing `/` the URL opens without any problem.

I need `.htaccess` code to set in the root directory to open PHP file like `login.php` as `/login/` or `/login` (without trailing `/`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `^([^/]+)/?$` and see if it works as expected.

Comment: After try this code RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php  i got 500 error

Comment: By simply making the trailing slash optional (and still having an all-encompassing capturing subpattern) you would expect this to create a rewrite loop (hence the 500 error). A request for `/login/` would rewrite to `/login.php` to `/login.php.php` to `/login.php.php.php`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is typical of a conflict with `MuiltiViews`. You should disable MultiViews at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

This explains why `/login` without the trailing `/` successfully serves the file - your `RewriteRule` is entirely bypassed in this scenario.

With MultiViews enabled, when requesting `/login/`, mod_negotiation mocks up a rewrite map and issues an internal subrequest for `/login.php` before mod_rewrite gets to process the URL. The path-info (trailing `/`) is added back, to become `/login.php/`. This is passed back for further processing and matches your overly-generic (`^(.*)/$`) `RewriteRule` *pattern*, resulting in an internal rewrite to `/login.php.php/` etc. Depending on your config, this could result in a 403 (as it can result in a malformed request), or a 404 (as you appear to be seeing).

Disabling MultiViews alone (as mentioned above) would solve this problem. However, you should also consider making your `RewriteRule` *pattern* more restictive. For example, to avoid matching URLs that already contain a dot (ie. have a file extension):

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Simply making the regex more restrictive may even "fix" the error. However, it would be MultiViews making the internal subrequest, not mod_rewrite (your rule would simply be bypassed).

> as `/login/` or `/login` (with or without the trailing `/`)

To allow the rule to work with either `/login/` or `/login` (ie. with or without the trailing slash) you would need to make the trailing slash optional, ie. `/?`. But you would also need to either make the preceding pattern non-greedy or include the slash in the negated character class in order to avoid capturing the trailing slash in the backreference.

For example, either:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Or,

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

But the second rule would only work with URLs that contain a single path segment, whereas the first would work with a URL of the form `/foo/bar/login`.

#### In Summary

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```